# Disable Open button after installation - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

After the installation i want my apk to open naturally on icon. Not after the installation on floating dialog.
So i want to disable the "Open" button after the installation and leave just the "Done" button functional.

This is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="3210"
    android:versionName="1.1.0"
    >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="10"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:isGame="false"

        >

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing|adjustPan"> 
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: This isn't possible, as far as I know.

Comment: @RyanM **That's right.**